# Proving Bisection with Einstein's Postulates

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames

A question from the "Einstein's Postulates" section from *Modern Physics* by Tipler:

> Suppose that $A', B',$ and $C'$ are at rest in frame $S'$, which moves with respect to $S$ at speed $v$ in the $+x$ direction. Let $B'$ be located exactly midway between $A'$ and $C'$. At $t' = 0$, a light flash occurs at $B'$ and expands outward as a spherical wave.

The question then goes on to ask for the difference in the arrival of the wave fronts at $A'$ and $C'$ according to an observer in $S$.

Of course, if we assume that $A'$ and $C'$ are equidistant to $B'$ according to an observer in $S$, then we can easily find the time it takes for the light to reach both points. However, **how can one show that $B'$ is still their midpoint?** That is my main question, and it is important because if $B'$ is not their midpoint according to an observer in $S$, then it complicates trying to find the difference in time. Moreover, I would like this to be shown **without** using the Lorentz transformation because this question was posed before this concept was introduced.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What are you allowed to use? I'm assuming there are some base axioms you're given based on the section title

Comment: Einstein's Postulates are

1.  The laws of physics are the same in all inertial reference frames.

2. The speed of light in a vacuum is equal to the value c, independent of the motion of the source.

Comment: It seems to me as if the question presupposes that $v \ll c$. I'm not sure you can really do this problem without at least working out the Lorentz transformations from the postulates.